# The election message in the community bulletin looks bad

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, accessibility, community-bulletin

...and you should feel bad.

[image: community bulletin]

I appreciate that elections are super-cool and exciting and should be highlighted, but that shade of red is not very readable on that shade of grey. Other people have pointed out that darkish red on dark grey is also extremely difficult to read when colorblind.

If it matters, this is reproducible on both Chrome and Firefox under Windows.

Comment: Darkish red on dark grey is also *extremely* difficult to read when colorblind

Comment: @NickT Said exactly the same thing I was going to say.  Will somebody  please think of the (colorblind) children!

Answer (score 6):

How about making it yellow instead? This stands out more in my opinion:

[image: Look at the sky, the colours shine for you]

This yellow (`#FBE253`) is already in the site palette, it's the colour used for the 10k flag queue count.

Comment: That looks much better to me. The red-on-grey is causing me eye strain personally, and I've been looking at it frequently to go and update myself with the election.

Answer (score 2):

I'm marking this as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), since the bulletin has undergone some network-wide changes a while back. It currently looks like this (it's from MathOverflow, but aside from the favicon it would look the same on Arqade):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This userscript code will fix the text for you (adapted from [this](http://somethingididnotknow.wordpress.com/2013/07/01/change-page-styles-with-greasemonkeytampermonkey/)):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       Community Bulletin Election Fix
// @description Makes the Election bulletin readable
// @match      http://*.gaming.stackexchange.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

function addGlobalStyle(css) {
    var head, style;
    head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    if (!head) { return; }
    style = document.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css';
    style.innerHTML = css;
    head.appendChild(style);
}

addGlobalStyle("#sidebar .module.community-bulletin a { color: #E6D364 !important; }");
```

Answer (score -11):

[I'll bet you clicked on it though.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134817/make-the-election-notification-more-prominent-on-the-frontpage)

Comment: Standing out is halfway, though.  If it's readable you'll also get people who are *interested* in it clicking it.